# Three.js create n meshes to form a smooth 90 degree donut

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, shapes, mesh

I am trying to find an algorithm to have the following generated in Three.js.
[Expected outcome (Pardon my drawing skills)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2iEI.png)
The amount of meshes to form the 90 degree donut, the thickness and the padding between them should be variable.

I know that you can create something like that with the TorusGeometry setting the radial segments to 2 and reducing the arc along the lines of:

```
const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 10, 3, 2, 100 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
const torus = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( torus );
```

But this does not work because as seen in my expected outcome, I need seperate meshes. So I researched further and encountered the ShapeGeometry. I think the way to go is with ShapeGeometry.

```
const generateArc = (padding, thickness, count) => {
     const arcShape = new THREE.Shape()
        .moveTo( 50, 10 )
        .absarc( 10, 10, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, false );
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do the correct math to generate these seperate mesh arcs around.
Is my approach with ShapeGeometry the right one? and if so how do I generate the right meshes with the Shape geometries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the 5th parameter in [the `TorusGeometry` constructor](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=buffergeometryuti#api/en/geometries/TorusGeometry) is the arc, and it looks like you're not using it.

`TorusGeometry(radius, tube, radialSegments, tubularSegments, arc)`

By using this arc, you could make a torus that's a fraction of 90 degrees. It's measured in radians, so to get 3 segments inside that 90-degree, it needs to be `(Math.PI / 2) / 3` or `Math.PI / 6`. See this working example below:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
render();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 50 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 15 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const MARGIN = Math.PI / 100;
    
    var torusArc = Math.PI / 6 - MARGIN;
    var geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 5, 1, 16, 32, torusArc);
    
    var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({side: THREE.DoubleSide});

    var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh2.rotation.z = Math.PI / 6 + MARGIN;
    var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh3.rotation.z = (Math.PI / 6 + MARGIN) * 2;

    scene.add( mesh1 );
    scene.add( mesh2 );
    scene.add( mesh3 );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}


function render(time) {
    camera.positi
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.140.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.140.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```